# What potential jobs could humans use dragons for?

Tags: fantasy-races, dragons

My society basically uses dragons for various purposes, but what sort of jobs might these dragons have besides pulling carts/carriages and mining diamonds?

Dragons in my universe tend to grow fast until about 5-6 years old, and leave the nest (which is inaccessible, at least in the wild) at around 3.

Females mature at around 6 years old and males at 5, also females are usually larger.
A mature dragon's head is about the size of a carriage (Think maybe a medium car).

By 3, their bodies are somewhere between asian/african elephant size. When they're young, but old enough to work they're about the size of a small pony/large mini-horse. They can be pretty dangerous to work with, especially if they're caught wild, since they have multiple ways of defending themselves (teeth, a scythe-like tail blade, hind claws, sharp horns, fire). Wing claws aren't as much of an issue since they're more used for gripping vertical surfaces like cliffs and walking vs. fighting.

Comment: You had better define what level of technology is present for the purposes of your question. As it stands, people are likely to assume this is with medieval technology given how fantasy doesn't often mix dragons and firearms (the exceptions are real, but a minority), but that might not be what you're looking for. You should also be more specific about the physiology of your dragons: six-limbed, four-limbed? Do they have huge grasping talons, or do they have anything resembling proper fingers? Lots of details can be added here that would improve your question, but we can't do that for you.

Comment: Are your dragons intelligent like Smaug?  Can they speak?   Or are these dog-intelligence dragons like How to Train your Dragon?

Comment: Please take a look at the [tour] and [help] so you can learn what kinds of questions are acceptable here.  This question is too broad: Stack Exchange works on the *single focused query, single focused response* model.  You're also asking too many questions: Stack Exchange works on the **ONE QUESTION ONLY** per post model.  Very likely, your query will be closed, giving you a chance to edit it into a more focused form.

Comment: They're sort of a medieval era. They're four-limbed, can grasp with their hind talons sort of like eagles/other birds of prey. They're pretty intelligent, around human level and maybe a little below, but can't speak.

Comment: This has appeared in the VTR queue.  Raw idea generation (also known as writer's block) is a poor fit for this site and is generally off-topic.  We need to convert this from an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) to an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609). "What can dragons do?" is always too broad unless you provide so much detail that you answer the question yourself.  "Could a dragon believably act as a crossing guard?" is the kind of Q StackExchange wants to see.  Specific.

Answer (score 3):

**Energy Providers**

The single biggest asset these dragons have that could be harnessed is their ability to breathe fire. We generally think of that as a bad and destructive thing, but then so is nuclear energy when applied in an uncontrolled manner; despite this nuclear powered electricity generation is one of the cleanest and most effective forms of generation we have.

In what I'm assuming is a medieval society, your dragons are an equivalent increase in power capability for a society. I can imagine dragons being used by blacksmiths to heat metal when they're shaping or smelting it. I can also imagine central heating being created centuries earlier when dragons are trained to heat lakes or wells, which then have the water piped through the local village. You could even have dragon-powered steam-driven industrial power plants.

Even if your locals had the same concerns with dragons in your town as many do over having a nuclear power plant beside them, you could harness their power remotely by having them produce charcoal, which was often used for smithing and heating homes back in those times. The amount of energy and manpower required to produce it would go down dramatically, so your society wouldn't even need to change all that much to accept dragons but the cost of energy would go down significantly.

Finally, there's one more use to which they could be put; air to ground attack units in a society that had no similar concept. A military with trained dragons would change the face of medieval combat almost overnight.

Answer (score 2):

**1) Logistic**

Pulling carts and carriages may be not the most optimal solution. It grounds them and limit their speed and carrying capacity. They should be able to fly with harnesses where packages are fixed to them. It would revolutionize the whole era, as often times logistic capacity and time was the limiting factor of commerce and communication.
The small ones, even the youngest ones could be used as fast, important message carriers.

Nowadays, even a microsecond lead in information delivery is highly priced in stock markets. In your universe it may not have reached that point, but good communication is essential and highly priced everywhere and anytime, especially if its reliable and could be kept secret. Meaning the more well-trained, faster, stealthier dragons should have higher prices. Since males are smaller, its a good job for them, unless they are also slower because of their size.

**2) Military**

I don't think I have to explain this. Their might may be able to decimate legions of men. The nation with more, stronger, better trained dragons will have the higher war potential. It will lead to an arms race... well dragon race, unless there is an easy counter for them. Wildness (with control) and destructive ability in the dragons will be highly priced by the military. I wouldn't be surprised if it leads to selective breeding for bigger and meaner dragons.

**3) Status symbol**

Just like horses or dogs, races may be held between high status and wealthy owners. The more ascetic dragons will have a higher prize and will be kept as a symbol to show around. Similarly, dragons bred with longer, nobler bloodlines will fetch a quite high price. They can be used as personal mounts for high status people. If they are seen as apex animals, they would certainly kept that way. Kings and nobles would race each other depending on various beauty standards and so on. This would lead to gifting the animals and the young ones with well documented bloodlines.

**4) Any kind of manual labor, really**

They can mine diamonds? They should be able to mine anything, trained to do almost anything which require only physical force. They would power factories and machinery by running around in small wheels generating electricity (if its in your setting). Ok, this may be too far fetched and not practical, but it would be funny.